# OTG on my Android

Tags: usb-drivers, usb-on-the-go

I have rooted Karbonn s1 Titanium running 4.1 Jelly Bean.

When I connect OTG with flash drive, it does not detect the flash drive. (The cable is alright, I verified.)

Is there any OTG driver problem or OTG device requires any hardware support that my device is lacking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I looked up, the Karbonn s1 titanium does not support OTG.

According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapdragon_(system_on_chip)#Snapdragon_S4

the Karbonn s1 Titanium, is a MSM8625Q chipset. Which does not support OTG

http://www.qualcomm.com/snapdragon/processors/s4/specs